# How to change image size from database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have image folder path from database as $banner_image_base :

```
/asset/images/promotion_banner/banner/2/2/2_xlIe1qJh_s300.jpg
```

From `/asset/images/promotion_banner/` is the default folder.

`banner` is `promotion_type`, the frist one of `2` is `promotion_banner_position`, the second one of `2` is `promotion_id` and the last one as the `image` `2_xlIe1qJh_s300.jpg`

I want trying to change the image size if the `promotion_banner_position` is changed

In my html there is `4` `promotion_banner_position` as `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. If the `promotion_banner_position` is change to be `1` the size should be :

```
width = 160px; height 940px
```

And if  `promotion_banner_position` `1` change to be `2`, `3` or `4` the size should be :

```
width = 320px; height 300px
```

Guys is that possible to change the image' size, that has been upload to database? thank you (:

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the target directory have write permission.
2. Check you didn't load the `image_lib` library twice.

and this is the code which I am using currently

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = "Mention your source location here";
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['height']   = "New Width";
$config['width'] = "New Height";
$config['new_image'] = "destination location";//you should have write permission here..
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```